# Get php variable using jquery on select tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to get a string from a php file, here:

```
$company = Company::find_by_id($_GET['company_id']);
$string = $company->output_information();
$output = array('key' => $string);

echo json_encode($output);
```

The main file has the following html:

```
<select id="step_one_check">
 // some options
</select>
<div id="div_company_data">TBA</div>
<div id="step_two" style="display: none">Step two<div>
```

and the following jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#step_one_check").change(function(){
            $("#step_two").slideDown();
            $.ajax({
                url : '../includes/encode/company_information.php',
                type : 'GET',
                data : "company_id=" + $("#step_one_check").val(),
                dataType : 'json',
                success : function (result) {
                   alert("success");
                        $("#div_company_data").html(result.key);
                },
                error : function () {
                   alert("error");
                }
            });

        });
```

The jQuery script makes step two slides down, but does not alert or #div_company_data. Any idea?

----- UPDATE -----

I've resolved the problem, it's my php file. After I included the Company class, the code worked.

Comment: @guradio Now it shows the alert, but not success alert

Comment: with error alert you need to check again you url path .. don't start from your js file path.. but start the path from the file which you run js file in .. I meant if you include the js file inside index.php  so start url from index.php

Comment: The console has my string {"key":"the string here"}, the .ajax somehow doesn't use the success function

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef The console has somehow correct string responded, so I assume that my url is okay.

Comment: you got the error alert .. and while your code is good .. I think the problem in the url

Comment: What does the network tab of the dev console say the response header is?